# Problema com subscribe em Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

À uns dias atrás eu fiz aqui uma pergunta por causa da tipagem e agora sei que nas versões mais recentes do Angular, a checagem de tipos ficou ainda mais estrita. Mas no código abaixo que serve para pegar os dados do utilizador, aparece o subscribe com um risco por cima. Era assim que eu fazia antes de a tipagem ficar diferente e dava certo. Gostava de saber porque agora o subscribe fica com risco.

```
export class ProfilePage {

  user!: string;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //  GET USER DATA
    this.userService.getuserdata().subscribe(
      (data: any) => {
        this.user = data['user'];

      },
      (error: any) => {}
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método que você usou está obsoleto e será removido em breve, segundo a mensagem de aviso.

Agora, quando quiser passar callbacks para `error` e `complete`, você deve passar um `Partial<Observer<T>>`, assim:

```
this.userService.getuserdata().subscribe({
  next: (data: any) => {
    this.user = data['user'];
  },

  error: (error: any) => {},
});
```

Mais informações: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments